# Getting Images from External Storage

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

I want to get all the images from a Screenshots folder in the android. But the code below is not working and also it does not throw any errors.
here is the code I am using

```
 val context = LocalContext.current
    val screenshots = mutableListOf<String>()

    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
    val selection = "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA} like ?"
    val selectionArgs = arrayOf("%/DCIM/Screenshots%")
    val sortOrder = "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED} DESC"

    context.contentResolver.query(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        sortOrder
    )?.use { cursor ->
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            screenshots.add(cursor.getString(columnIndex))
        }
}
```

Comment: `DCIM/Screenshots` On most devices they are in Pictures/Screenshots.

Comment: `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` That column is often not available. Better use .RELATIVE_PATH.

Comment: that didn't work!

Comment: Post your code.